# Minimum Length of XML Namespace Name?

Tags: c#, xml, uri, xml-namespaces

I have been playing with validating some XML when I noticed C# throws out namespace <s>prefixes</s> names with text before a colon that is less than 2 characters in length.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Example xmlns="a:example" />
```

is invalid in C# but

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Example xmlns="a1:example" />
```

is not?

Is this part of the XML standard or am I seeing something weird in C# here?

Here is some sample code.

```
// Create fake XML.
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.AppendChild(xmlDocument.CreateElement("Example", "a:example"));
//xmlDocument.AppendChild(xmlDocument.CreateElement("Example", "a1:example"));

// Display the XML to the user.
using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
 using (XmlWriter xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter)) { xmlDocument.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter); }
 Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
}

// Infer schema.
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
 xmlDocument.Save(stream);
 stream.Position = 0;
 new XmlSchemaInference().InferSchema(XmlReader.Create(stream));
}

// If we got this far then we are happy.
Console.WriteLine("We are happy");
```

This will generate a XmlSchemaException:

```
The Namespace 'a:example' is an invalid URI.
```

with an InnerException of FormatException:

```
The string 'a:example' is not a valid Uri value.
```

Changing to the commented line results in the code working.

XmlConvert.ToUri(String s) is on the stack trace and likely to be causing this. I found some decompiled source [here](http://typedescriptor.net/browse/members/546569-System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToUri%28String%29) which led me on the path to [Uri.TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx) presumably C# expects a valid URI scheme?

Thanks for your time :-).

Comment: `a:` is not a namespace prefix. It's a URL scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Note that this answer may not be correct - section 3.1 of RFC3986 ABNF for schema allows single letter namespace prefixes. There are no one letter scheme registered, so it either customary restriction or there may exists some other document prohibiting one-letter scheme names.

---

Uri scheme for namespace Uri (what you incorrectly name "namespace prefix") should be at least 2 characters long:

[RFC3986, section 3.1 Scheme](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

> ...Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters beginning with a
>      letter and followed by any combination of letters, digits, plus
>      ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-").
>
> ```
>  scheme      = ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "." )
> ```

Note: Namespace prefix is "prefix" portion of following sample. See [Namespace in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl) for details.

```
 <prefix:ElementName xmlns:prefix="scheme:path" />
```

Comment: Interesting. That would explain it thanks!

According to Wikipedia I should be able to get away with namespace Uris that aren't actually Uris but Microsoft must be more diligent in their checking!

"Although the term namespace URI is widespread, the W3C Recommendation refers to it as the namespace name. The specification is not entirely prescriptive about the precise rules for namespace names (it does not explicitly say that parsers must reject documents where the namespace name is not a valid Uniform Resource Identifier), and many XML parsers allow any character string to be used."

Comment: @Levenkov But according to rfc2234, *X means zero or more occurrences of X, so surely this rule allows a scheme name to be a single character?

Comment: @MichaelKay - hmmm... ABNF to me does not match text... but clearly it should take precedence - maybe it is indeed allowed (but no single-letter scheme is registered....)